# Select the first word on the left of a string in snowflake

Tags: sql, string, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column (mycolumn) in my snowflake table (mytable) whose content has this pattern :

JohnDoe - Client Number One

MaryJane - Client Number Two

I would need to extract the first portion on the left of the string (JohnDoe,MaryJane - with no whitespace behind).

I tried to use the following approach, but I got stucked because I could only remove the first two block of words to the right, but not the - (dash) and the white spaces.

```
select substring(mycolumn,1,length(mycolumn)- CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(mycolumn))- CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(mycolumn))) from mytable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(mycolumn, '^[^ ]+')
from mytable;
```